# Function to return TRUE if a value is present within a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns of data that share 90% of items, but not all. I need to find the differences.

I think I could simply use a function that takes a cell in column A and check if such a cell exists within column B. The data format is a string.

What function could I use for that in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in C1 and copy down

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,B:B,0))
```

Comment: The cell content is a string, I should have said that.

Comment: It does not matter.  MATCH returns a number if the value is found and an error if not.

Comment: Actually there are semicolons, not commas - but it works otherwise - thank you!

Comment: That is a local setting.  Where I am from it is `,` most of Europe is `;`